# if/else statement problem: else statement does not work

Tags: python

I am a beginner in programming and I am trying to implement if...else statement but being failed. I have an array list and I have to check it does not contain a specific value. But the else statement does not work.

```
#For an example:
a=[10,12.0,13.0]
b=[12.0]

if a <= b:
 print("something")
else:
 print("others")  #else statement doesn't work
```

Comment: The problem is not the `else`, the problem is the `if` condition :) . You're comparing two _lists_, what were you expecting to happen? Please read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types) to understand what really happens when you try to compare two lists with `<=`.

Comment: Yes, did you mean `if (len(a) <= len(b)):`?

Comment: The first element of `a` is less than the first element of `b`, so the `if` is true and the `else` does not execute.

Comment: Did you mean `if b[0] in a:`?

Comment: What was your purpose to compare two lists? This isn't the way to check if a value is inside a list. For example, `if 5 in [1, 5]` is a proper one.

Comment: `and I have to check it does not contain a specific value` If that's what you want to do, why are you comparing with `<=`?  That is not the correct operation to check for an element in a list.

Comment: Yuo could use `<=` with sets instead of lists. It will `set1 <= set2` will tell you if `set1` is a subset of `set2`.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I want to compare every single value of array a with b and if values in array a have less than or equal of the single value of array b then execute something eg. a+b else a-b. I do not know if it is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is an iteration. Currently you're asking if your list `a` is less than or equal to your list `b`, but semantically this doesn't have a lot of meaning. In fact, Python seems to somewhat unintuitively select the first element of each list in order to perform the comparison. Thus, in the example code you give it will always evaluate as `True` since `10 < 12.0`.

However, if you add an iterator like so:

```
a=[10,12.0,13.0]
b=[12.0]

for ai in a:
    for bi in b:
        if ai <= bi:
            print(f"a={ai} b={bi} and a is strictly smaller.")
        else:
            print(f"a={ai} b={bi} and a is equal or greater.")
```

In this manner you can compare every item in `a` with every item in `b`.

However, if you simply want to ensure that `12.0` is not in `a`, Python provides a much simpler way:

```
a=[10,12.0,13.0]
b=[12.0]

if b[0] in a:
    print("The list contains the selected value.")
```